# How to iterate through self.superview in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a class called **LabelView** inheriting from *UIView*. In the story board have a view dragged and inheriting from **LabelView**. Now I want to iterate through the ***self.superview*** to set the attributed text of each view. Please suggest a method to do so.
Here is my code:

```
int i=0;
    for (UIView *view in labelView) {
        if ([view isMemberOfClass:[LabelView class]]) {
            [view setTag:i];
            NSArray *symbols = @[@"+", @"-", @"*", @"/"];
            NSString* symb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [symbols objectAtIndex:i]];
            UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:view.bounds.size.width*0.80];
            NSAttributedString *labelOperator=[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", symb]attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: labelFont}];
            CGRect textrect;
            textrect.origin=CGPointMake(12, 0);
            textrect.size=[labelOperator size];
            [labelOperator drawInRect:textrect];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"fail");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something like this:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isMemberOfClass:[LabelView class]]) {
//DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
}
```

The above fast enumeration code iterates through all the subviews in your `self.view` and checks if the view is a member of your custom class which is `LabelView`. If it finds one, then the statements inside the `if` condition gets executed. Hope it helps!

Comment: self.view won't work as i don't have a property called "view". And every time i try something i.e self.superview or self.subview, i get a Thread 1:signal SIGABRT error.

Comment: And if you have some properties declared in LabelView that you would like to set/access just cast view like: LabelView *lbl = (LabelView *)view;

Comment: Basically how can I iterate through my views superview?

Comment: Where do you execute the above piece of code you've written?

Comment: If your "self" is subclass of UIView than you should do self.subviews else if it is subclass of UIViewController than you have to access view property of view controller and then subviews like self.view.subviews.

Comment: self is a subclass of UIView.

Comment: You can connect your labelView in using IBOutlet rt. After that you can call that name in the code.   In your code you can connect using IBOutlet LabelView *labelView to storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to go from your label view to the superview and iterate through **its** subviews.

```
for (UIView *label in labelView.superview.subviews) {
   if ([label isKindOfClass:[LabelView class]]) {
       // configure the label
   }
}
```